# I cannot filter through my array on a component that is rendered by Route. Why isn’t it working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React but this problem i am having is really bothering me. I feel like it is so simple. 
So in my root, `<App/>`, component, I am passing my states as a prop to my `<PostDetails/>` component and then I am using the parameter `:postId` on my `<PostDetails/>` component to filter through the `posts` array and get a single post. The problem here is that when I try to filter through my array, it returns an empty array. How can i make it work? Why is this happening?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home/Home'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import About from './components/About'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import PostDetails from './components/Home/PostDetails'


export class App extends Component {

  state ={
    posts: [
      {id: 1, title: 'title1', content: 'Tempor aute pariatur qui non ea id. Pariatur id aute dolore duis excepteur reprehenderit amet aliqua minim proident non et mollit. Fugiat est adipisicing excepteur ad. Exercitation voluptate nulla magna amet dolor pariatur nisi eiusmod sint aliquip consectetur mollit anim duis. Proident qui irure Lorem aliquip id excepteur in tempor veniam. Non voluptate amet ea excepteur nulla enim aliqua ipsum officia exercitation minim.'},
      {id: 2, title: 'title2', content: 'Tempor aute pariatur qui non ea id. Pariatur id aute dolore duis excepteur reprehenderit amet aliqua minim proident non et mollit. Fugiat est adipisicing excepteur ad. Exercitation voluptate nulla magna amet dolor pariatur nisi eiusmod sint aliquip consectetur mollit anim duis. Proident qui irure Lorem aliquip id excepteur in tempor veniam. Non voluptate amet ea excepteur nulla enim aliqua ipsum officia exercitation minim.'},
      {id: 3, title: 'title3', content: 'Tempor aute pariatur qui non ea id. Pariatur id aute dolore duis excepteur reprehenderit amet aliqua minim proident non et mollit. Fugiat est adipisicing excepteur ad. Exercitation voluptate nulla magna amet dolor pariatur nisi eiusmod sint aliquip consectetur mollit anim duis. Proident qui irure Lorem aliquip id excepteur in tempor veniam. Non voluptate amet ea excepteur nulla enim aliqua ipsum officia exercitation minim.'},
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact><Home posts={this.state.posts}/></Route>
          {/*<Route path='/about' component={About}></Route>
          <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}></Route>*/}
          <Route path='/posts/:postId' render={(props) => <PostDetails {...props} posts={this.state.posts} />} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}


export default App
```

PostDetails.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class PostDetails extends Component {

    state = {
        id: null,
        post: null
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const id = this.props.match.params.postId;
        const singlePostArray = this.props.posts.filter(post => post.id === id)
        this.setState({
            id: id,
            post: singlePostArray[0]
        })


    }
    render(){


        console.log(this.state.post);
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className="card-panel">
                    <p>{this.state.post}</p>
                    <p>{}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(PostDetails)
```

Comment: OP, what is the value of ``this.props.match.params.postId`? what's the value of `this.props.posts`?

Comment: So when I enter `/posts/2` URL in the browser, I can acces my `this.match.params.id` , in the case it is 2. And my post id from the state of root component is `post.id` Inside the filter method. They both show as 2. But the filter method is returning an empty array for some reason. I don’t know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use constructor and then have to pass the props to super(props).

Comment: I can access my props in PostDetails component. But even though the both id values are the same, for some reason filter method returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your prop values in ComponentDidMount, instead of this set them in the constructor of your class component.
Like this:

```
class PostDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props); // you will get props here, set your state now
    }
```

Comment: OP is not setting the prop values anywhere.

Comment: I can access my props in `PostDetails` component. But even though the both id values are the same, for some reason filter method returns empty.

Comment: I think you should convert id to Int using parseInt(this.match.params.id), then check

Comment: `const id = parseInt(this.match.params.id); ` //change this line